# How do I setup a Temporary Network

Tags: networking, nas

My wife and I are going to live in a hotel for a few months, and then move into a new house.
We have two MacBooks, a PC, a NetGear RN314 NAS, two Airport Time Capsules, and a Canon printer.
I also have an 8-Port Netgear GS108 switch.
My question is: can I simply plug everything into the switch and make all the devices get along?
I currently have AT&T Internet service. I will not be able to use its Gateway, obviously.
I run all the devices on the 192.168 network, some fixed IP, some not.
The NAS does not have Wi-fi, the others have both Wi-fi and Ethernet.
Will this work without a router? If not, any recommendations?
The hotel has Wi-fi, the house will have a structured panel that I have no clue about except it goes to all the rooms, and supposedly the Internet provider connects to it, where it goes places.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Don't expect so much from hotel wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can get a vaguely useful signal from hotel WiFi - some of them you can barely get email over...

You could set up one of the Macs as your gateway/router, using Internet Sharing [System Prefs > Sharing].
I haven't actually enabled it in this pic, but you would share from Wifi to Ethernet...
[Don't enable Remote Login or Management unless you are certain you need it - you will be unnecessarily exposing your machine if you do.]

[image]

Connect the Mac to one port of your Ethernet switch & everything else to the other ports. After that, the Mac will provide routing & DHCP to all the other devices.
It may be wise to disable WiFi on all the other devices so they will naturally use Ethernet.
The Mac logs into the hotel WiFi, then is in charge & providing routing, gateway, DHCP & firewalling for your subnet.
You will, of course, need it to stay awake whenever any device needs the internet, but not for inter-device communications once DHCP has been set up. Devices should [but may not always] hang onto their last-known IP Address. If they don't, you'll have to wake the Mac to refresh them.
You can otherwise use the Mac as normal, the connection sharing shouldn't interfere with its own operation.